# Emacs syntax highlighting of optional parts

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-lock, emacs-faces

I'm trying to write a derived mode from fundamental-mode. Assuming that I have this regexp : `A ((foo)bar)? B`, how can I tell emacs to use the following faces ?

- `font-lock-keyword-face` on `A`
- `font-lock-warning-face` on `foo` (but not `bar`)
- `font-lock-constant-face` on `B`

I have tried to use this following code :

```
(defvar myregexp
  "\\(A\\) \\(?:\\(foo\\)bar \\)?\\(B\\)")

(setq mylang-font-lock-keywords `(
  (, myregex 1 font-lock-keyword-face)
  (, myregex 2 font-lock-warning-face)
  (, myregex 3 font-lock-constant-face)
))
```

But it does not work with the string `A B` (emacs report a missing capture).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use subexp highlighters with laxmatch enabled to have font-lock-mode ignore missing groups in matches:

```
(setq mylang-font-lock-keywords
      `((,myregexp (1 font-lock-keyword-face)
              (2 font-lock-warning-face nil t)
              (3 font-lock-constant-face))))
```

The forth element of each subexp highlighter is the `laxmatch` argument.  If `t` font-lock-mode ignores this highlighter if the corresponding group in the first element is not found in the match result of `myregexp`.

See [Search-based Fontification](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification) in the Emacs Lisp manual for more information.

Comment: That's only needed for the 2nd match, but it's OK to use it everywhere (I actually think it was a mistake for font-lock to be non-lax by default).  Also, you have wisely changed the rule to use `myregex` only once, which will speed up the code by about 3.  But you need to wrap the keywords into one more pair of parentheses.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for your corrections. I have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The way your regexp is specified, you'd need two spaces between `A` and `B`.  Either pull the second space inside the optional foobar part or use `*` or `?` after it.

Comment: Typo, it's fixed. The missing capture error is still there (`Error during redisplay: (error "No match 3 in highlight (1 font-lock-constant-face)")`)

Comment: The error you cite ("No match 3 in highlight (1 font-lock-constant-face)") doesn't mak much sense and doesn't match your code either (your code has 3 associated to font-lock-constant-face, not 1).